# Jenkins: multiple jobs with one shared resource

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing

So I have a dynamic number of jobs which all have only one build step.
at some ("random") point of its execution, each job run some application which couldn't have more than one instance at a given time.
In general I do want parallel run of the jobs. but I still need some synchronization when two or more jobs trying to run the above application at the same time.

I though about using the [Locks and Latches plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locks+and+Latches+plugin) , but I can't see how this will help me in my situation.

Ideas will be more than welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the application from a separate job (let's call it APP_JOB) that you would invoke via Parametrized Trigger Plugin (as a build step, not as a post-build step) from your other jobs, with an option to wait for it enabled. By default Jenkins won't run parallel instances of APP_JOB.